# Why does Visual Studio Code refuse to run and display this error message?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed Visual Studio Code for the first time and upon trying to run it, it halts with an alert that says:

> Please make sure the following directories are writeable:
>
> /Users/~/Library/Application Support/Code
>
> /Users/~/.vscode/extensions

The first path should be writable, but the second one doesn't seem to exist.  I searched hidden files and it's still not where it should be.

System: OSX High Sierra, 10.13.6

Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

Comment: On macOS (according to https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/install-extension/) VS Code looks for extensions in `$HOME/.vscode/extensions` by default. What is `$HOME` set to?

Comment: That is: I suspect that you've got it configured to use `~/.vscode/extensions` (somehow) and it's not expanding the `~` (because that's a shell-specific thing).